# How do I use RxJava 2 to orchestrate a race with retry?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Suppose we have a set of flaky (sometimes failing) parsers that may or may not be able to handle a given file i.e. a given parser either succeeds with some probability `p > 0`, or fails always (`p=0`). Is it possible to use RxJava to have this set of parsers subscribe to a stream of incoming files and 'race' to parse the file?

Given that it is possible for the parser to fail initially but still be able to parse the file, it is necessary to have them retry with some backoff policy. Given that it is also possible for no parser to be able to handle a given file, the retry count should be capped.

Implementing exponential backoff is relatively easy to implement using `retryWhen` with something like this ([source](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/)):

```
source.retryWhen(errors ->
                errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i)
                      .flatMap(retryCount -> Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(5, retryCount), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
);
```

However, setting up a parallel race is something I cannot figure out how to do. It seems like the `amb` operator is what we want here, but applying it to an arbitrary number of streams seems to require using `blockingIterable`, which (I think) defeats the purpose of the race as it blocks. I have been unable to find anything useful relating to this use case of `amb` on the internet.

My attempts thus far resemble something like this:

```
Set<Parser> parserSet = new HashSet<>();
parserSet.add(new Parser(..., ..., ...));
// Add more parsers 
int numParsers = parserSet.size();

Flowable<Parser> parsers = Flowable.fromIterable(parserSet).repeat();

fileSource
    .flatMap(f -> parsers.take(numParsers)
                         .map(p -> p.parse(f))
                         .retryWhen(/* snippet from above */)
                         .onErrorReturn(/* some error value */)
             ).take(1)
```

`Flowable` introduced the `.parallel()` operator which just recently got the addition of `ParallelFailureHandling` ([see this pr](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5202)) which has a `RETRY` method, but I can't seem to get the flowables to stop retrying after one of them has returned.

Is this problem solvable with RxJava?

Comment: It doesn't say that that it needs specifically a blockingIterable, why did you thought it needed one?

Comment: `Flowable.amb()` takes `Iterable<? extends Publisher<? extends T>>`, I didn't see a way to get them into that form with a `blockingIterable` call. I did also try using `.reduce(Flowable::amb)` but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: What about `Observable.amb` or `ambWith` (I've not much experience with it myself, so bear with me while I ask stupid questions)?

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I believe that `Flowable` and `Observable` are essentially equivalent except in their handling of backpressure. They expose (almost) the same operator APIs, including the in question `amb` and `ambWith`. It's worth mentioning that this is my first venture into the world of Rx so I likely have no idea what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the reasonable assumption that your parsers are synchronous, something like

```
Set<Parser> parserSet = new HashSet<>();
parserSet.add(new Parser(..., ..., ...));
// Add more parsers 
int numParsers = parserSet.size();

ArrayList<Flowable<T>> parserObservableList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Parser p: parserSet) {
    parserObservableList.add(Flowable.fromCallable(() -> p.parse(f))
                                     .retryWhen(/* Add your retry logic */)
                                     .onErrorReturn(/* some error value */));
}

Flowable.amb(parserObservableList).subscribe(/* do what you want with the results */);
```

should meet your requirements.